# VM revert on Scalar Multiplication in pre-compiled contracts

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, precompiled-contracts, elliptic

I tried to build a wrapper around the precompiled contracts as follows:
https://gist.github.com/AlexXiong97/9c24bbd4541323a61fa63100860a5f89

If you paste it into Remix and deploy it, inputting any (valid) scalar into `scalarBaseMult` function would result in a VM revert, which indicates a failure in parameters provided to the precompiled contract.

However, I'm pretty confident the parameters are correct as I generate them directly from [Cloudflare's bn256](https://github.com/cloudflare/bn256) library which is exactly what Geth uses. Here's my script:
https://gist.github.com/AlexXiong97/217f42ee4d0dedc6182b182134caeed9

If you input `(1, 2, 3)` into `scalarMult`, the correct result will be returned which makes sense as (1,2) is indeed a point on the bn256 curve `y^2 = x^3 +3`

I once suspect my computed generator coordinates are wrong, but as [specified](https://github.com/cloudflare/bn256/blob/master/curve.go#L18) here: the generator is (1, -2) mod p, where p's value is [here](https://github.com/cloudflare/bn256/blob/master/constants.go#L16), thus I'm quite sure there's nothing wrong with their value.

Can anyone help me understand what might cause the VM exception?

Comment: Could you provide a link to a failed transaction on one of the public test networks, please? It might help with troubleshooting.

Comment: @Thomas I didn't deploy it to the live network. I don't think we need to in order to test its functionality. poking it inside Remix or just in a ganache sandbox is pretty much the amount of info you will get even when you deploy them on chain.